# $[A_1, H] =[A_2, H] = 0$ but $[A_1, A_2] \neq 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, linear-algebra

I am having a difficult time understanding this problem.

> Suppose $[A_1, A_2] \ne 0,$
>           $[A_1, H] = 0,$
>           $[A_2, H] = 0.$
>   Show that the energy eigenstates of $H$ are in general degenerate.

It seems to me that if $[A_1, H] = 0$ and $[A_2, H] = 0,$ then $H$ shares eigenstates with both $A_1$ and $A_2$. Hence, any eigenstate of $H$ is also one of $A_1$ and $A_2\Rightarrow[A_1, A_2]=0$. Clearly, this is not so, since the question forces me to assume the opposite. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In terms of the proof, notice that if $[A, B] = 0$ so $AB = BA$, then $A$ maps any eigenspace of $B$ to itself. This is the core "ratchet" which you use to screw on  simultaneous diagonalizability to commuting observables: Because of this, B's eigenspaces are spanned by eigenvectors of A, leading to simultaneous diagonalizability. So if $H$ is nondegenerate, the eigenspaces are all 1-dimensional, then all eigenvectors of H are their own eigenspace and are therefore eigenvectors of both $A_1$ and $A_2$, hence those two commute. The only way out is if some eigenspace is multidimensional.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It is? Are you reading "if" as "if and only if", or "degenerate" as referring to a degenerate matrix? Because "$H$ is degenerate" usually means "$H$ admits two linearly independent eigenvectors that have the same energy", which means "some eigenspace has dimension at least 2", hence if it is not that, all of its eigenspaces have dimension 1.

Comment: @Chris my apologies, that was a huge lapse on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$ commutes with $A_1$, then it will indeed share an eigenbasis with it. Your mistake is in supposing that it will share the *same* eigenbasis with both $A_i$s.

Examples are easy to provide:

- On the trivial side, if $H=E_0\mathbf 1$ is trivial, then it shares an eigenbasis with $A_1=x$ and it shares an eigenbasis $A_2=p$, but it cannot share an eigenbasis with both.
- On the more physically meaningful side, the total angular momentum (as well as spherically-symmetric hamiltonians like the hydrogenic one) shares an eigenbasis with $L_z$ and ditto for $L_x$, but it can't do so with both. To make a shared eigenbasis you need to break the spherical symmetry and choose a quantization axis, and you will get different bases depending on which axis you choose.

In every degenerate eigenspace of $H$ you can always find non-commuting observables of this sort. This is easy to prove: if $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1|}\ket 1$ and $\ket 2$ share an energy eigenvalue, then you can choose 
$$
A_1=\ket 1\bra1-\ket 2\bra 2\quad\text{and}\quad A_2=\ket1\bra 2+\ket2\bra1,
$$
or in matrix language
$$
A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
A_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
in the $\{\ket 1,\ket 2\}$ basis. You can easily check that these matrices don't commute. To be more explicit, here are eigenstates of $H$ which are not eigenstates of $A_2$, thought there is indeed some (other) basis for this eigenspace which $H$ shares with $A_2$.  What is this other shared eigenbasis? What are the matrix representations of the two operators in the two eigenbases?

The only way you can avoid this is by giving the observables absolutely no breathing room for this sort of monkey business, and that is by having one-dimensional, nondegenerate energy eigenspaces. If this is the case, then for each eigenspace where $H$ and $A_1$ share a basis $\{\ket\phi\}$, $A_1$ needs to share with $H$ a basis of $\mathrm{span}\,\{\ket\phi\}$, which can differ from $\ket\phi$ by, at most, a trivial phase. The shared eigenbases are then the same, and $A_1$ must commute with $A_2$.

Comment: This is missing help with the proof, but is otherwise a great answer.

Comment: The last paragraph is a proof of the contrapositive (if $H$ is not degenerate, then $[A_1,A_2]=0$) and thus a proof of the desired statement.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It was a little confusing because you defined a different $A_1$ and $A_2$ so it seemed like you were referring to them rather than referring to Tae Hyoun Park's $A_1$ and $A_2$, but that last paragraph does not make sense under those assumptions. You are right that if we convert the first sentence of the last paragraph to "Assume a nondegenerate energy spectrum." Then indeed as you say, every eigenspace has dimension one, so the eigenbasis of $H$ is unique an so the simultaneous eigenbasis between $A_1$ and $H$ is just the eigenbasis of $H$. You're right, that's valid.

Answer (score 0):

If $[A,B]=0$ then there is a unitary transformation $U_{A,B}$ that diagonalises both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously. This transformation depends on the pair of commuting operators $(A,B)$, so that for a different pair there could be a different unitary. Assume that all the eigenvalues of $H$ have multiplicity 1. Then there exists a unique (up to a phase factor) unitary $U$ that diagonalises any $A$ such that $[A,H]=0$ simultaneously, and such that the eigenvalues of $H$ are increasing along the diagonal. Hence you get a family of unitaries which taken together form an Abelian group (i.e. $S^1$). Any other operator $B$ that commutes with $H$ must then be diagonalised by the same unitary, which would then imply that $[A,B]=0$ (you can verify this in the base that diagonalises $H$ and then get back). Hence at least an eigenvalue of $H$ must have a multiplicity higher than 1.

If this is the case for only one then now there is a choice of unitaries that diagonalise $H$ which is unique up to a $U(2)$-equivalence (observe that $U(2)$, contrary to $S^1=U(1)$, is no longer Abelian). In principle it is then possible to find non-commuting unitaries $U_{A,H}$ and $U_{B,H}$ that diagonalise the pairs $(A,H)$ and $(B,H)$ respectively, which would not necessarily imply $[A,B] = 0$.